# Kubernetes capture Memory dump when memory reaches specific value?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I have some of my pods running a single container, and some running two. I have given the `Xmx` 4GB for each container, what I want is if the container reaches 3 GB, Kubernetes takes the memory dump.

Is it feasible?

Comment: feasible, but it's not vastly different to doing it outside of kubernetes. You need to monitor the process or container memory, trigger a job that probably uses jmx to do the heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can follow something like below.

1. Create a shell script

   - Use it to check for your process (looks like a Java process) and
     extract the used memory and trigger a memory dump.
   - As @Matt has mentioned, this is a generic solution

     - Use `ps` command for setting the process
     - Use `jcmd <PID> GC.heap_dump <output-file>`
2. Add this file into your docker image
3. Then add a CMD to run the shell script in background and your app in foreground.